# Tabela de precedência de operadores do C

Tags: c, c++, operadores

Em C por que `y = (y=2 , y+3)` retorna 5 se o `+` tem prioridade em relação ao `=` e a `,`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você tem várias prioridades aí. A primeira coisa que será executada é

```
y = 2
```

Este *statement* se encerra aí por causa do [operador de vírgula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

Depois o código executa

```
y + 3
```

Como antes o `y` valia 2, agora ele vale 5. Como o resultado de uma lista de instruções é o resultado da última, o resultado de

```
(y = 2, y + 3)
```

é o resultado desta última, ou seja, 5. E este é o valor que será em guardado em `y` no final, já que é o objetivo da expressão toda.

```
y = (y = 2, y + 3)
```

Provavelmente sua dúvida esteja no operador de separação de instruções. Ele torna expressões em instruções separadas. Este operador é quase esquecido mas está lá na [tabela de precedência](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence). Note que este operador tem a mais baixa precedência.

Talvez sua dúvida se deva ao fato que o operador de atribuição, o `=`, tenha associatividade da direita para esquerda, portanto o que está à direita executa primeiro.

Em geral os parênteses não são necessários mas neste caso eles são usados para evitar ambiguidade e um comportamento indefinido.

Escrevendo de outra forma:

```
y = 2;
temp = y + 3;
y = temp;
```

No fundo, exagerando nos parênteses para ficar mais visível, pode ser visto como:

```
(y = ((y = 2), (y + 3)))
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Operator/Precedence.cpp).

Por que a última expressão é usada? Porque C definiu assim. Porque parecia ser a forma mais lógica de usar um resultado. Só um deles poderia ser usado, então você ficava entre o primeiro e o último (outros fariam bem pouco sentido até porque eles podem até não existir) e é mais provável que você precise do último resultado do que do primeiro que possivelmente ainda será manipulado nas instruções seguintes.

Comment: Minha dúvida era que se o operador de separação tem a menor precedência ele não seria executado por último? Aí o y + 3 seria executado primeiro.

Comment: Primeiro em relação a que? Isto é importante. Quando falamos de precedência de operador é só em relação à operação realiza diretamente por ele, não pelas sub-expressões realizadas pelos seus operandos. Então o que antes da vírgula é executado primeiro, depois é executado o que está depois da vírgula porque ambos são sub-expressões que precisam ser completadas para servirem como resultado para a expressão maior que é onde a vírgula é usada. Daí este operador ignora tudo que está antes da última vírgula e considera como seu resultado o que foi obtido depois da vírgula, que no fim é atribuído a y

Answer (score 4):

Só para chamar à atenção que o operador `_ , _` é um dos poucos operadores em C 
que garante uma ordem de execução dos seus argumentos.

Só é garantida ordem de cálculo nos seguintes operadores:

```
a && b
a || b
a ? b : c
a , b
```

Exemplo de algumas expressões com **semântica indefinida**

```
i = ((y=2) + y+3)
i = ++i + i++;    // undefined behavior
i = i++ + 1;      // undefined behavior
f(++i, ++i);      // undefined behavior
f(i = -1, i = 2); // undefined behavior
f(i, i++);        // undefined behavior
a[i] = i++;       // undefined behavior
a = i + (i=2);
a = (i=2) + i;

cout << i << i++; // undefined behavior (C++)
```

**UPDATE**: Acerca de **semântica indefinida**

Semântica indefinida é uma das grandes causas de bugs de SW.
Do ponto de vista do compilador corresponde a: 
*este construtor **não 
é permitido/válido**, mas não vou verficar para não perder tempo. Se o programador o usar, não me responsabilizo, vale tudo!*

Qual a saída do programa:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int x=1;
    printf("%d %d %d\n", x++,x++,x++);
    return 0;
}
```

No meu gcc 5.2 deu `3 2 1`; experimentei noutra máquina e 
deu `1 2 3`.

Estão ambas de acordo com a comportamento prescrito pelo C, são ambas válidas; se um compilador se lembrar de formatar o disco, tambem é uma implementação válida desta instrução.

Já agora, `gcc -Wall` alerta para alguns destes casos.

Um exemplo ilustrativo bastante interessante e que descreve como essas coisas surgem foi postado [nesta resposta do SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9945955/2896619) (não se trata de uma tradução livre, e sim de uma redescrição em Português):

> Imagine duas implementações de um compilador em C: a versão da empresa
>   FooCoorp (que eu vou chamar de `fcc`) e a versão da empresa BarCoorp
>   (que eu vou chamar de `bcc`). Suponha que na compilação do código
>   `M(A(), B())` o compilador `fcc` interprete isso como "Primeiro
>   executa `tempA = A()`, depois executa `tempB = B()`, e então executa
>   `M(tempA, tempB)`. E suponha que  na compilação do mesmo código o
>   compilador `bcc` interprete isso como "Primeiro executa `tempB = B()`,
>   depois executa `tempA = A()`, e então executa `M(tempA, tempB)`. O
>   resultado final, nesse exemplo, vai ser o mesmo. Mas,
>   independentemente de produzir o mesmo resultado ou não, a ordem de
>   execução ai é arbitrária. Quem está certo? O comitê que definiu a
>   especificação semântica da linguagem poderia indicar uma ordem
>   específica para esse exemplo, mas e para todas as outras combinações
>   semânticas possíveis e ainda não necessariamente pensadas? Pode
>   ser que tal comitê decida por deixar essa questão em aberto (isto é,
>   ambas as opções são válidas, dependendo das escolhas de
>   quem implementar o compilador a respeito de opiniões pessoais ou
>   questões de otimização). Acaba sendo esse o caso quando as empresas
>   FooCoorp e BarCoorp pertencem ambas ao comitê de decisão. :)

Esse exemplo ilustrativo trata de C, mas o mesmo poderia valer para a semântica de qualquer linguagem.

---

\thanks{Luis Vieira} pelas sugestões e exemplo fcc / bcc

Comment: Seria bom deixar claro para futuros leitores o que exatamente vc quer dizer com "semântica indefinida". :)

Comment: @LuizVieira, tens toda a razão, mas é realmente um conceito com alguma cmplexidade... Juntei algumas linhas: se tiveres paciência, está à vontade para completar / corrigir.

Comment: Ficou bem melhor, obrigado! Eu já havia votado +1, mas votaria de novo se pudesse. :)

Comment: Eu fiz uma edição pra tentar complementar com um exemplo bacana lá do SOEn, ok?

Comment: @LuizVieira, Obrigado duas vezes ☺

Comment: Caso não tenha ficado claro para alguém, a vírgula que separa argumentos de função não é o “operador vírgula”. A vírgula que separa declaração de variáveis também não. Acho que o uso mais comum do verdadeiro operador vírgula seria num `for(;; ++i, ++j){}`.

Comment: @marcus: certissimo. (é uma subtiliza que facilmente passa desapercebida)

Comment: Existe uma proposta para deixar as regras (um pouco) mais fáceis em C++: http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0145r1.pdf porque certos detalhes causam problemas até para os maiores especialistas da linguagem. Mas por enquanto é só uma proposta (e só para C++, não C), então é bom continuar evitando essas expressões que alteram a mesma variável mais de uma vez.