# Ponteiros e referências aninhadas

Tags: c, c++, ponteiro, referência

Estou com uma dúvida na interpretação (na forma que eu leio meu código) em umas atribuições em ponteiros na linguagem C.

Eu não entendi a lógica das seguintes atribuições:

"Se `i` e `j` são variáveis inteiras e `p` e `q` ponteiros para `int`,  quais  das  seguintes  expressões  de atribuição são ilegais?"

Enunciado do exercício:

```
a) p = &i;
b) *q = &j;
c) p = &*&i; 
d) i = (*&)j;
e) i = *&j;
f) i = *&*&j;
g) q = *p;
h) i = (*p)++ + *q;
```

Estou com dúvida nos items C, D, E e F, pois não entendi a lógica das seguintes atribuições... A, B, G e H eu não tenho dúvidas nas atribuições, apenas as que utilizam "*&var".

Como eu interpreto estas atribuições em C?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

Não tem muito segredo se você sabe como funciona o [`*` e o `&`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125793/101) isoladamente.

- C) pegue o endereço de `i`, depois pegue o conteúdo deste endereço (que obviamente é o valor de `i`) e depois pegue o endereço deste conteúdo e guarde em `p`.
- D) Esta sintaxe não é possível
- E) Pegue o endereço de `j` e depois pegue o conteúdo deste endereço para guardar em `i`.
- F) Pegue o endereço de `j`, pegue o conteúdo deste endereço e pegue o endereço dele e finalmente pegue o conteúdo deste endereço para guardar em `i`.

A interpretação depende [precedência e associatividade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55353/101) dos operadores.

Isto é feito para demonstração. Não faz sentido fazer este tipo de coisa. Pelo menos não desta forma.

Comment: Ahh, entendi como funciona... Valeu pela resposta!! e, realmente, achei um tanto "absurdo" esse tipo de atribuição kkkkkk