# Obtendo resultados diferentes com passagem por valor e passagem por referência

Tags: c, funções, ponteiro, parâmetros

Eu estou testando esses exemplos de códigos em C:

[Call by value](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_function_call_by_value.htm)

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* function definition to swap the values */
void swap(int x, int y) {

   int temp;

   temp = x; /* save the value of x */
   x = y;    /* put y into x */
   y = temp; /* put temp into y */

   return;
}

int main () {

   /* local variable definition */
   int a = 100;
   int b = 200;

   printf("Before swap, value of a : %d\n", a );
   printf("Before swap, value of b : %d\n", b );

   /* calling a function to swap the values */
   swap(a, b);

   printf("After swap, value of a : %d\n", a );
   printf("After swap, value of b : %d\n", b );

   return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
Before swap, value of a :100
Before swap, value of b :200
After swap, value of a :100
After swap, value of b :200
```

Até aqui tudo bem, agora a saída do segundo exemplo esta me intrigando:

[Call by reference](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_function_call_by_reference.htm)

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* function definition to swap the values */
void swap(int *x, int *y) {

   int temp;
   temp = *x;    /* save the value at address x */
   *x = *y;      /* put y into x */
   *y = temp;    /* put temp into y */

   return;
}

int main () {

   /* local variable definition */
   int a = 100;
   int b = 200;

   printf("Before swap, value of a : %d\n", a );
   printf("Before swap, value of b : %d\n", b );

   /* calling a function to swap the values.
      * &a indicates pointer to a ie. address of variable a and 
      * &b indicates pointer to b ie. address of variable b.
   */
   swap(&a, &b);

   printf("After swap, value of a : %d\n", a );
   printf("After swap, value of b : %d\n", b );

   return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
Before swap, value of a :100
Before swap, value of b :200
After swap, value of a :200 # aqui era pra ser 100
After swap, value of b :100 # e aqui era pra ser 200
```

Por que os valores estão saindo invertidos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A função `swap()` faz o que se espera de uma função de troca, então o segundo código está certo e o primeiro está errado, afinal no primeiro nenhuma troca é feita. Claro que provavelmente o objetivo do primeiro era mostrar que o valor fica isolado, ainda que um péssimo exemplo.

Quando se passa o valor o parâmetro não tem relação direta com as variáveis que originaram o argumento. O que é passado é copiado para a função, qualquer alteração feita nesses valores dentro da função só valem lá dentro. Acabando a função as variáveis usadas como argumentos na chamada da função estão com seus valores intactos ali.

Quando se passa por referência, o que está passando é o endereço de um valor, possivelmente o endereço de uma variável,como ocorre nesse caso. Então qualquer alteração nesse valor afeta o local original onde ele estava, portanto ao sair da função o valor estará alterado.

Quando um parâmetro é um ponteiro, o que é copiado é o endereço de memória de alguma coisa. Qualquer manipulação desse local tem visibilidade por toda a aplicação. Essa é a base do que chamamos "passagem por referência". O ponteiro serve justamente pra criar uma [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101), então ao inés de acessar um valor diretamente, o acesso é feito indiretamente através do endereço contido nele. Ele é uma espécie de envelope.

Quando passa um valor normal, está fazendo uma fotocópia de uma carta. Qualquer alteração nesta cópia não reflete na carta original. Quando usa o ponteiro, ele é um envelope que contém a carta. Então qualquer alteração na carta é "definitiva".

- [Entenda o operador &](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/125798/101)
- [Diferença entre ponteiro e referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/101)
- [Explicação prática de alguns exemplo dos operadores de ponteiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/85600/101).

Comment: entao no segundo caso ele fez a troca do endereco da memoria isso? +1

Comment: @NikoBellic Não, ele troca o valor, assim como no primeiro exemplo. A diferença é o tempo de vida da alteração. No primeira, a alteração existe só dentro da função, no segundo ela é feita direta na variável da função principal. Este exemplo de `swap()` é péssimo. Esses cursos de internet podem até dar uma base, mas ensinam muita coisa errada. Depois eu coloco como seria uma função `swap()` melhor que faz o que você disse.

Comment: Pensando bem não vou por outra porque a outra função não tem nada útil para o aprendizado que se tentou passar aí. É um assunto completamente diferente.